# permalink for category pages and posts

Tags: urls, permalinks

Can you please help me?

For getting post url I use: `<?php the_permalink() ?>`
But for pages and for categories? If I use `<?php the_permalink() ?>` on categories it displays post url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently no way in core to get the current archive / category / tag / custom taxonomy URL. I have a patch waiting for that to be added [right here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18660). For now though, you could just use the code in the last patch on that ticket:

```
<?php
/* Get the current archive link 
 *  
 * @param $paged boolean whether or not to return a link with the current page in the archive, default true 
 * @since 3.3 
 */ 
function get_current_archive_link( $paged = true ) { 
        $link = false; 

        if ( is_front_page() ) { 
                $link = home_url( '/' ); 
        } else if ( is_home() && "page" == get_option('show_on_front') ) { 
                $link = get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ); 
        } else if ( is_tax() || is_tag() || is_category() ) { 
                $term = get_queried_object(); 
                $link = get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ); 
        } else if ( is_post_type_archive() ) { 
                $link = get_post_type_archive_link( get_post_type() ); 
        } else if ( is_author() ) { 
                $link = get_author_posts_url( get_query_var('author'), get_query_var('author_name') ); 
        } else if ( is_archive() ) { 
                if ( is_date() ) { 
                        if ( is_day() ) { 
                                $link = get_day_link( get_query_var('year'), get_query_var('monthnum'), get_query_var('day') ); 
                        } else if ( is_month() ) { 
                                $link = get_month_link( get_query_var('year'), get_query_var('monthnum') ); 
                        } else if ( is_year() ) { 
                                $link = get_year_link( get_query_var('year') ); 
                        }                                                
                } 
        } 

        if ( $paged && $link && get_query_var('paged') > 1 ) { 
                global $wp_rewrite; 
                if ( !$wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) { 
                        $link = add_query_arg( 'paged', get_query_var('paged'), $link ); 
                } else { 
                        $link = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( $link ) . trailingslashit( $wp_rewrite->pagination_base ) . get_query_var('paged'), 'archive' ); 
                } 
        } 
        return $link; 
}
```

Comment: that's an awesome script :) thanks allot!

and how do I use it? put it in functions.php and call it echo get_current_archive_link(); ?

Comment: Yes, or just change the function to `echo` instead of `return` :)

Comment: nice :) will check how it works right now.

Answer (score 2):

for pages, it should be the same as for posts;

to link to category archives, try to use the category ID with

```
<?php echo get_category_link( $category_id ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link

edit:
to get the link to the category of the current category archive, try:

```
<?php echo get_category_link( get_query_var('cat') ); ?>
```

Comment: I want to use it in the theme, so I cannot define $category_id 12 times (my blog category count). I just need to get current category url.